# file provisioner in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the below terraform code that is working , It does the job , it copies from my source the file to the destination ec2 instance.
But what i dont understand why the content of my local file is created in /home/ec2-user/scripts file on the ec2 instance .  Any idee what to do ?

```
resource "null_resource" "copy-set-aws-profile-script" {
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/scripts/set_aws_profile.sh"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/scripts/set_aws_profile.sh"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      host        = aws_instance.deployer_server.public_ip
      private_key = tls_private_key.deployer.private_key_openssh
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.deployer_server,
    aws_key_pair.endava_deployer_ssh_key,
  ]
}
```

I tried to use content instead of source in the file block but the same result .

also tried to use in the destination section : /home/ec2-user/scripts but same result

I expect that the file should be under /home/ec2-user/scripts/set_aws_profile.sh in my ec2 instance

Comment: Wait, so the code is working? Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: the issue is that the file is not uploaded as I want , it uploads it as /home/ec2-user/scripts file instead of /home/ec2-user/scripts/set_aws_profile.sh . And I can't figure it why

Comment: So the shell script is missing or not?

Comment: did the code work?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your destination attribute

```
destination = "/home/ec2-user/scripts/set_aws_profile.sh"
```

Just change the location where you want to save the file... you don't need to pass the file name, just the folder

```
destination = "/home/ec2-user/scripts/"
```

> Don't forget the "**/**" in the end